# Programmatic WCF Message Security with Certificates

Tags: wcf, x509certificate, wshttpbinding

I've written a self-hosted WCF service using WSHttpBindings and I'm trying to implement message-level security using certificates I've generated myself.  Unfortunately I'm getting a buried exception (via the Service Trace Viewer) stating "The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized."

A couple notes:

1. This has to be done in code, not
   in configuration
2. (Server/Client)Cert are certificates
   that are in the local machine store
   with accessible private keys to my
   user while debugging.
3. I've googled the hell out of this and
   found a good resource for setting up
   WCF message based security [here](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%20-%20Use%20Certificate%20Authentication%20and%20Message%20Security%20in%20WCF%20calling%20from%20Windows%20Forms)

I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Most of this stuff seems straight forward except for creating the endpoint identities.  It fails with the same message whether I use DnsEndpointIdentities, cert based ones, or no identities at all.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Server side:

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding
    {
      Security =
      {
        Mode = SecurityMode.Message,
        Message = 
        {
          ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate,
          AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256Rsa15
        }
      }
    };

_host = new ServiceHost(this)
{
  Credentials =
  {
    ServiceCertificate =
    {
      Certificate = ServiceCert
    },
    ClientCertificate =
    {
      Certificate = ClientCert,
      Authentication =
      {
        TrustedStoreLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
        RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck,
        CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust
       }
    }
  }
};
var address = new Uri(string.Format(@"http://serviceaddress"));
var ep = _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IService), binding, address);
ep.Address = new EndpointAddress(address, EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(ServiceCert));
_host.Open();
```

Client side:

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding
    {
      Security =
      {
        Mode = SecurityMode.Message,
        Message =
        { 
          ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate,
          AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256Rsa15
        }
      }
    };
var address = new Uri(@"http://serviceaddress");
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(address, EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(ServerCert));
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, endpoint)
    {
      Credentials =
      {
        ServiceCertificate =
        {
          DefaultCertificate = ServerCert,
          Authentication =
          {
            RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck,
            TrustedStoreLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
            CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust
          }
        },
        ClientCertificate =
        {
          Certificate = ClientCert
        }
      }
    };
var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734673.aspx) helped tremendously.  I think the root of the problem was setting the following message security parameters to false:

```
httpBinding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
httpBinding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
```

So now the overall code for the server side looks more like:

```
var httpBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
httpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
httpBinding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
httpBinding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
var httpUri = new Uri("http://serviceaddress");
_host = new ServiceHost(this, httpUri);
_host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.TrustedPeople, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, serverThumbprint);
_host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
_host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.TrustedStoreLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine;
_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetaService), httpBinding, httpUri);
_host.Open();
```

and the client side:

```
var httpBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
httpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
httpBinding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
httpBinding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
var httpUri = new Uri("http://serviceaddress");
var httpEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(httpUri, EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("name of server cert"));
var newFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMetaService>(httpBinding, httpEndpoint);
newFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.TrustedPeople, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "client certificate thumbprint");
newFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.TrustedPeople, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "server certificate thumbprint");
var channel = newFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question and providing this code only approach. Seems like a lot of folks struggle to achieve this so I can point to them to this question in the future.