# How can I encrypt, but not secure WCF messages?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security

I've created an app that has machines talking to each other across the net. I'd like to use NetTCPBinding and encrypt the messages. However I don't want or need certificates or windows authentication. I try to set the security mode to Message to get encryption and transport security to none to avoid the certificates/windows authentication but still I get:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The caller
>   was not authenticated by the service. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token
>   could not be satisfied because authentication failed.

Here's the relevant code:

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570939/wcf-message-security-without-certificate-and-windows-auth

Comment: Why? This seems like an unusual goal - there's little point in encryption if the attacker can just splice himself in between your two endpoints. This would just be fake security. I recommend you use transport security with a server certificate for most basic encryption needs (HTTPS-style approach).

Comment: @Sander - is there a way to do this so a downloadable desktop application can be installed via an installer on a user's machine without them having to do anything or know about certificates, or having to generate certificates for each install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An answer from this question works: [selfhosting wcf server - load certificate from file instead of certificate store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441266/selfhosting-wcf-server-load-certificate-from-file-instead-of-certificate-store/4883044#4883044)

My code:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("cert.pfx", "");

host = new ServiceHost(MessageProvider, address);
host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = certificate;
host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, address);
host.Open();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for: **[Message Security with an Anonymous Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733938.aspx)**. I suppose the problem in your case is that your service is not specifying a certificate on server-side:

> Initial negotiation requires server authentication, but not client authentication

So when instantiating the service try to do something like (from MSDN):

```
myServiceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
     StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
     StoreName.My,
     X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
     "00000000000000000000000000000000");
```